# What leverage would the US government have to stop the other governments from collectively making humanity's first official contact with ETs?

Tags: aliens, government, politics

Suppose a federation of extraterrestrial civilizations have been monitoring Earth for thousands of years. They are ready for official relationships with the human civilization, but also have a strict policy of respecting self-determination, such that it has been up to the humans to make the pitch. As the evidence of the ET presence around Earth mounts, humans globally start demanding their governments to acknowledge the prevailing public awareness of the matter and to make contact. The relationships with the advanced civilizations would however mean a technological revolution toward a post-scarcity money-less economy to end the industries based on fossil fuels and human labor that have been the source of power for the class of elites who have so far been exerting ultimate influence upon the human world. For this reason, the oligarchs in the US, Russia, Saudi Arabia, etc oppose making the contact, and they control their governments. But the other governments, notably the Chinese and Europeans, are willing to make the contact.

Given that the technological revolution and the new economy would render insignificant many traditional aspects of a superpower, what political leverage would the US and others have in order to block the first contact, apart from propagandas against the ETs?

Comment: UN treaty?  UN troops to back it up?

Comment: Their propaganda might become ineffective the second they start to try and approach the aliens they're trying to demonize. If they have this valuable tech and everyone knows it, propaganda that says "ets bad" will likely be simply ignored. Appealing to the United nations might also won't work, since China is a part of the permanent members as well and has the power to vet measures against the contact. Going a la Napoleon and trying to impose economic withholds towards these countries, since other might be willing to go along with this, might (but I don't see it as  guaranteed to) work.

Comment: Despite the authoritarian regime I would expect Russia to be at the forefront of making contact, while the US (recently investigated by Stanford and found to be an Oligarchy) and China would the its biggest opponents. Just looking at the extreme censorship, control of information and misuse of rules to retain control there's no reason China's elite would want any contact with the aliens

Comment: VTC as too story-based. [Worldbuilding.se] is focused on helping you develop and consistently use the rules and systems of your fictional world (including alternate history) wherein an infinite number of stories can be told. Storybuilding (which we don't do) is about plot, circumstances, and the decisions of characters (whether an individual or a nation). You don't sound like you're asking us to help you iron out your world. It sounds like you're asking us to help you write your story. That's off-topic.

Comment: @Demigan Neither the U.S. nor China would be the biggest opponents. Faced with the inevitability as described by the OP, both would act with enormous enthusiasm with the ulterior motive of being the *only* contact source and therefore the only beneficiaries. I suspect most nations would act this way. Considering how many SJWs are in the U.S. right now, the (unrealistic) carrot of a utopian hell (I mean society) would drive my nation mad to be first in line.

Comment: Which brings up a point, Miranda. Your question states that the aliens "have a strict policy of respecting self-determination," but what they're offering would change the lives of every individual and nation on the planet for both the better and the worse. How do your aliens balance that policy? Planet-wide majority vote? Representative government decision (not all governments are like this)? Does the vote need to be a simple majority or a super-majority or unanimous? Do the aliens back away if even one individual says no? Where's the line?

Comment: @Demigan
China is the top crude oil importer, and is also the leading country in renewable energy electricity production, so, from a technological-economic standpoint, they would be on the pro-ET camp against the beneficiaries of fossil fuels. Also, if the Chinese government is to maintain its communist guise, they could not morally oppose the radical shift toward a post-scarcity system that would obviate the fundamental principles of capitalism such as prices (abundance is counter to price).

Comment: Questions about political machinations are almost always off-topic (opinion-based). You can have politics in any story churn and wobble and come out any way you wish.

Comment: @JBH 

I expect the answers to suggest economic/political mechanisms/properties by which some human nations could assert long-term non-militaristic opposition to the opening up of the human civilization to the extraterrestrials, such that the universe has no official representation of the whole humanity. That is the general rules and systems of the world I would like elucidated, wherein different stories may be conceived.

Comment: @JBH "How do your aliens balance that policy? 

The objective of their self-determination policy is to minimize conflicts on the humans' side. They are willing to recognize any formal democratic decision-making assemblies as representative instruments of conflict-minimizing self-determining cooperating humans, and the aliens would consider the largest of such assemblies as the greatest conflict-minimizer, of which the United Nations would be the presumed candidate. So, that would be their starting point, ready for some formulation of a treaty via the UN.

Comment: @JBH
But how the aliens would recognize self-determination is less relevant to my question than how the human world may be configured such that it is unable to form a global representation in order to initiate the first official approach as "the human civilization" to the extraterrestrials.

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid I can't vote to reopen. Our site can answer questions about what a government is, but how a government acts is storybuilding and that's off-topic. @user535733 is completely correct, no matter which government and what starting point (aka, a specific date) you choose, you (the author) can always contrive a series of completely plausible (even probable) circumstances that produces the very outcome you wish. Sorry.

Comment: "Questions about political machinations are almost always off-topic (opinion-based)."
How a civilization may be configured politically so as to limit its possible interactions with other civilizations should be well within the purview of world-building. I'm not asking for a discussion of what is good or bad. I'm asking for a description of a mechanism that would objectively limit a certain possibility.

Comment: You asked "**what political leverage would [actors] have in order to [do something]*", not "*how can a civilization be configured politically to [do something].*" The latter would be far too broad --the turgid speculation of assorted political systems fills whole floors of libraries.  Fundamentally, you seem to be asking "*How do I get to [this result]?*"  The answer is simply good storytelling. Audiences will forgive many flaws and plot holes if they like the characters and the plot and the writing. Just don't hit them over the head with awkward stereotypes and tropes (bad storytelling).

Answer (score 0):

**Make a good example of yourself**

If you can show the federation that you are potentially the social and polictical flagship of humanity embodying all the good within it, then they are more likely to notice and take you seriously than acting like a xenophobic cult spewing half baked propaganda to every channel possible.

**Tell them about your grand societal achievements**

The US, despite having a big amount of racism and injustice in the past has managed to beat back both slavery and racism by a big amount during the 1800s and 1950s-60s.

Even now the US is beginning to make a serious effort to push against insitutional racism.

Answer (score 0):

What power would any Government have? A lot of organisations and even individuals have equipment that could be directed at the aliens and it is almost certain that someone somewhere would attempt to make contact, probably thousands of them, so the ball would really be in the alien’s court. In terms of physical contact the US Government, if so minded, could prevent any launches from the US attempting to make contact, but could not stop the Russians or Chinese and could only apply diplomatic pressure in Europe.

At the end of the day if the aliens wanted to make contact they would and there would be nothing the US or anyone could do could do about it. Nor would it be clear what the consequences of contact would be or what the alien’s intentions were be they good, bad or inscrutably enigmatic.